# C# code returns different results from stored procedure executing manually

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using a stored procedure to get back an integer result. In C# code, for same parameter values are returning 0 but when I try manually in SSMS it returns 1.

C# code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckLabelExists", connection)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    };

    cmd.Parameters.Add(SQLHelper.GetSqlParameter("@LabelName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, labelName));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(SQLHelper.GetSqlParameter("@IdParentLabel", SqlDbType.Int, labelId));

    SqlParameter returnValue = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    result = (int)returnValue.Value;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCheckLabelExists]
    @LabelName nvarchar(50),
    @IdParentLabel int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Exists bit = 0;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Label] 
               WHERE Name = @LabelName 
                 AND IdParentLabel = @IdParentLabel)
    BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WITH LabelHierarchy AS 
        (
            SELECT IdLabel, IdParentLabel, Name
            FROM [Label]
            WHERE IdLabel = @IdParentLabel
            UNION ALL
            SELECT l.IdLabel, l.IdParentLabel, l.Name
            FROM [Label] l
            INNER JOIN LabelHierarchy h ON l.IdParentLabel = h.IdLabel
        )
        SELECT TOP 1 @Exists = 1 
        FROM LabelHierarchy 
        WHERE Name = @LabelName;
    END
    
    SELECT @Exists AS LabelExists;
END
```

Comment: Why would you expect something else other than `0`? By default a procedure returns `0` when it succeeds and you don't have an explicit `RETURN` clause in the above so `0` will be returned. I would suggest that it does not `RETURN` `1` in SSMS either. Don't forget the `RETURN` value and the dataset(s) returned are *completely* different. Though, personally, I would define `@Exists` as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: Return value is 0 in this SP. Why don't you simply check the result of ExecuteScalar() instead? That is what you really want to do here (select @Exists ...). A simpler procedure would be doing a count(). If ExecuteScalar() result is not 0 it exists.

Comment: It's from 2009, but still as relevant as ever: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using SELECT or RETURN instead of OUTPUT](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output)